# AVAudioEngine, AVPlayer, AVPlayerViewController - Control Center controls becomes disabled when AVPlayerViewController plays video

Tags: swift3, ios10, avplayerviewcontroller, avaudioengine, control-center

I am using `AVAudioEngine` to play audio files and `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerViewController` to play videos.

and Control Center notification are enabled `UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`

Control Center works perfectly for audio files (play/pause/next/prev/slider) if no video file is played (if no `AVPlayerViewController` instance exists)

but as soon as I play a  video file and then dismiss the `AVPlayerViewController` and play audio file, all the controls in the Control Center becomes disable.

refreshing nowPlayingInfo does not work - it only updates the thumbnail and audio title

[image]
[image: After dismissing AVPlayerViewController]

After dismissing AVPlayerViewController